# Any solutions for perspective view openGL qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have the following problem, when I zoom in on the image. I have not been able to solve it. I am currently developing in Qt with c ++. I have a question about orthogonal projection and perspective projection. I need to zoom without traversing the image. I tried to make the `glViewport` bigger, but it does not work for me. The `xmin`, `xmax`... are the maximum and minimum values ​​for each axis.

```cpp
void MeshViewer::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    int side = qMin(width, height);
    if ( height == 0 )
        height = 1;
    glViewport(((GLint)(width - side)/2.0), (GLint)((height -side)/2.0), (GLint)side, (GLint)side);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml) specifies the mapping of normalized device coordinates to window coordinates (pixels).

If you want that the entire geometry which is inside the clip space, is mapped to the window, then it has to be:

```
glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
```

Answer (score 0):

What the window displays is a frustum, defined by six planes. Normally, these planes are parallel, as in a cube. Anything that lies outside the frustum is not displayed.

"Zoom" may be interpreted, in a generic way, as "see bigger, nearer, more detail".

There are several ways of achieve the zoom effect:

- Scale the objects. This works, the flaw is that objects (or parts of them) may lie before the *near* plane or behind the *far* plane of the frustum.
- Move the camera towards the object. Same matter with near/far planes. Also, take care of moving through the model, you can set a "barrier" (perhaps a box) to prevent the camera moving too deep.
- For an orthogonal projection, set left/right/top/bottom planes nearer to the object. This makes the frustum smaller, thus it's normal that some objects get clipped.
- For a perspective projection you can do the same trick as with orthogonal. This trick is just to reduce the *FOV* (field of view) angle. If objects are too far, the perspective effect may be less obvious.